# Trying to export Teachable Machine Model But returning error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have just exported a teachable machine model in the h5 file format, and i set it up locally in my development environment but i keep getting this error

```
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'DepthwiseConv2D' using config={'name': 'expanded_conv_depthwise', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'kernel_size': [3, 3], 'strides': [1, 1], 'padding': 'same', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'groups': 1, 'activation': 'linear', 'use_bias': False, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'depth_multiplier': 1, 'depthwise_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'scale': 1, 'mode': 'fan_avg', 'distribution': 'uniform', 'seed': None}}, 'depthwise_regularizer': None, 'depthwise_constraint': None}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}
```

Here is my code:

```
from keras.models import load_model  # TensorFlow is required for Keras to work
from PIL import Image, ImageOps  # Install pillow instead of PIL
import numpy as np

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = load_model("keras_model.h5", compile=False)

# Load the labels
class_names = open("labels.txt", "r").readlines()

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)



# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open("jap span.jfif").convert("RGB")

# resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

# turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.5) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# Predicts the model
prediction = model.predict(data)
index = np.argmax(prediction)
class_name = class_names[index]
confidence_score = prediction[0][index]

# Print prediction and confidence score
print("Class:", class_name[2:], end="")
print("Confidence Score:", confidence_score)
```

Expected an output of which class and confidence level but error returned